# Unable to get values from input fields by ID

Tags: jquery

I have form fields like this:

```
<input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' onchange='' class='percent' id='task_complete_percentage[]' style='width:40px;' type='text' />
<input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' onchange='' class='percent' id='task_complete_percentage1" + counter + "' style='width:40px;' type='text' />
<input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' onchange='' class='percent' id='task_complete_percentage2" + counter + "' style='width:40px;' type='text' />
<input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' onchange='' class='percent' id='task_complete_percentage3" + counter + "' style='width:40px;' type='text' />
```

Fields are added dynamically and I want to sum all values.

```
 $('[id *= "task_complete_percentage"]').change(function(){             
 $('[id *= "task_complete_percentage"]').each( function () {
 console.log('test');
  }); 
});
```

But only first field is working, but if do like this I can see all values. What I'm doing wrong?

```
 $("#addElement").click(function(){             
 $('[id *= "task_complete_percentage"]').each( function () {
   console.log('test');
 }); 
  });
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for your selector? Why not try `$('#task_complete_percentage')`?

Comment: OK, I see now in the HTML that the IDs are different. So why not use a CSS class for each of these elements and access them by className as suggested above by Gavin?

Comment: Seems like invalid HTML as well; `id='task_complete_percentage[]" + counter + "'`

Comment: getting same result aswell

Comment: @Stefan sorry, my mistake first element does not have a counter

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any need for the ID parameters - we can address these fields through jQuery using other parameters/techniques

```
<div id="task_complete_percentage_fields">
  <input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' class='percent' type='text' />
  <input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' class='percent' type='text' />
  <input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' class='percent' type='text' />
  <input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' class='percent' type='text' />
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="addElement">Add another row</div>
```

Maybe use some CSS to handle the widths, rather than setting the style attribute for each one

```
#task_complete_percentage_fields input.percent { width:40px }
```

Fields are added dynamically and I want to sum all values.

```
// Init the Sum Variable
var percentageSum = 0;

// Create a Function to Tally the Percentages
function sumPercentages(){
  // Reset the Sum
  percentageSum = 0;
  // Loop through the Fields
  $('#task_complete_percentage_fields input.percent').each(function(k,v){
    var $v = $(v);
    // Strip non-numerals
    $v.val( $v.val().replace( /\D/g , '' ) );
    // Sum the Percentages
    percentageSum += 1*$(v).val();
  });
  // Output the Sum
  $('#output').text( percentageSum );
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Attach a delegated live event to the fields within the div
    $('#task_complete_percentage_fields').on( 'change' , 'input.percent' , function(){
      sumPercentages();
    });

    // You can also call the same function from any other function
    $('#addElement').click(function(){
      $('#task_complete_percentage_fields')
        .append("<input name='task_complete_percentage[]' value='' class='percent' type='text' />");
      sumPercentages();
    });

    sumPercentages();

});
```

Check this out at JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/P5f4J/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this--

```
$(".percent").each( function () {
 console.log('test');
  });
```